# Нужно сделать, чтобы интерфейс работал

Tags: python, pyqt

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(681, 451)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 651, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 651, 281))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 651, 31))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("pushButton{\n"
"color:red;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 400, 651, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Скачать видео"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать место для сохранения"))
```

Answer (score 2):

В конце файла необходимо добавить проверку:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(681, 451)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 651, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 651, 281))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 350, 651, 31))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("pushButton{\n"
"color:red;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 400, 651, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Скачать видео"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать место для сохранения"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В следующий раз буду подробнее объяснять

Comment: не работает все равно

Comment: Странно, я проверил, работает. Ты импортировал библиотеки? (через pip)

Comment: можешь готовый рабочий код скинуть?

Comment: Я допустил не большую ошибку, можете проверять)

Comment: import в твоем коде оштбку выдает, выделен красным

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: красным выделялся, я в сублайме работаю и он не пишет ошибки,а только выделяет, код работает, от души

Comment: Рад был помочь)

Comment: а можешь сделать чтобы он работал?

Comment: чтобы функционировал, так вернее

Comment: Извини, но нет времени, погугли в интернете. Можешь посмотреть плейлист по этой ссылке: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3ma5waVGb0